# Need to find whether overlap is present in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I haev been stuck in a problem from quite some time and trying to figure out how to solve this using sql.

I have a table which has 3 columns :

```
LowerLimit UpperLimit Code
1              10       A
10.01           20      B
20.01           40      C
40.01           100     D
```

So in such case I need to check if there overlap present or not. The Upperlimit should not match with the LowerLimit of the next row and the permissible difference is only 0.01 . Is it possible to solve this using queries or do I need to iterate the whole range and find whether there is no overlap???

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `exists` to get the first row of overlap.  For your specific logic:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.upperlimit >= t.lowerlimit and
                    t2.upperlimit < t.upperlimit + 0.01
             );
```

If you want both rows, you can formulate this as a `join` or using a second `exists` to get the previous row.

I don't like your data representation.  I would simple make the lower bound *inclusive* and the upper bound *exclusive*.  Then the next lower bound could simply be the previous upper bound.  You would not be able to use `between` but that is a bad idea anyway on numbers with decimal parts.